# print one line from foreach in c#

Tags: c#, printing, symbols

I am trying to print the symbol (trimmedLine) and value from a list (matchedSymbols), but instead, it prints all the values of all the valid symbols for each symbol. I tried not using the foreach loop, but then it prints the value for the last symbol searched, which is invalid. Below is my current code for the method:

```
public void searchSymbolTable()
    {
        string searchingForFile = "";
        string[] searchFile;

        Console.Write("Enter the name of the search file: ");
        searchingForFile = @"../../" + Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Searching symbol table...");
        Console.WriteLine();

        while (!File.Exists(searchingForFile))
        {
            Console.Write("File not found, try again or enter 1 to exit: ");
            searchingForFile = @"../../" + Console.ReadLine();
            if (searchingForFile == @"../../1")
            {
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }

        searchFile = File.ReadAllLines(searchingForFile);


        matchedSymbols = new List<symbols>();
        var space = ' ';

        foreach (string line in searchFile)
        {
            try
            {
                var trimmedLine = line.Trim();
                var tokens = trimmedLine.Split(space);

                trimmedLine = checkSymbol(tokens[0]);

                matchedSymbols.Add(mySymbols.ToList().Find(symName => symName.ToString() == trimmedLine));


                if (matchedSymbols[matchedSymbols.Count() - 1] == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("ERROR - Symbol {0} not found in symbol table.", trimmedLine));
                }
                else
                {
                   foreach(symbols s in mySymbols)
                   {

                           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-10} {1}", trimmedLine, s.value));

                   }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                if (Console.CursorTop % 20 == 19)
                {
                    Console.Write("Press any key to continue ...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your inner foreach should be iterating over `matchedSymbols` and not `mySymbols` -- is that correct? Also, are you expecting `trimmedLine` to match more than one symbol in `mySybols`?

Comment: Changing it to matchedSymbols does not correct the problem though I changed it because it makes sense that it should be used. It still prints out the last value it looked at. The number of time each symbol and value is printed seems to correlate with its position in the list (i.e. the first symbol is printed out once, the second symbol is printed twice). As for trimmedLine, it will find a match for one symbol since I am not allowing duplicates.

Comment: What exactly is your output currently, and what are you expecting it to be?

Comment: Right now I'm getting (in columns): N 98, a123 98, A123 98...... It should be N 5, a123 -45, A123 -55. The 98s are coming from the value of the last symbol in my symbol table file.

Comment: So that 98 is the final symbol in "mySymbols"? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: MySymbols should only have the validated symbols and their attributes, so 98 shouldn't be there because all my 98 values have invlid symbols. In another method, I read from a file, validate the symbols and attributes and add them to a sortedset called mySymbols.I have checked and printed out that the symbol table (mySymbol) actually only have valid information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only looking for one match, you don't need the inner foreach...

I've replaced your `Find` with some Linq that will select the first match (or return null)

```
var trimmedLine = line.Trim();
var tokens = trimmedLine.Split(space);

trimmedLine = checkSymbol(tokens[0]);

//look for the match, select the first (null if no matches)
var matchedSymbol = mySymbols.FirstOrDefault(symName => symName.ToString() == trimmedLine);

//if null (no match)                
if (matchedSymbol == null)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("ERROR - Symbol {0} not found in symbol table.", trimmedLine));
}
else
{
    //print the match
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-10} {1}", trimmedLine, matchedSymbol.value));
    //add the match to your collection of matches
    matchedSymbols.Add(matchedSybol);
}
```

Comment: The search for a match in the symbol table works fine. However, it is when I try to attached the symbol's value to the found symbol that I have a problem. That is what the inner for each loop is for except I am not getting the right value.